# Match everything until a pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression:

```
(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]* ) (?<class>[^ ]+) *(?<level>[^ ]+)[ -]+(?<message>.*)
```

Trying to match a java stacktrace, a sample of which is:

```
2015-01-28 18:48:33,484  grails.plugin.jms.JmsGrailsPlugin                   INFO   - registering listener for 'sendPostLinkByEmailToUnbindedContacts' of service 'postCreatedActivityListener' to TOPIC 'post.created'
2015-01-28 18:48:35,569  sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory              WARN   - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ws/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.8.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2015-01-28 18:48:37,809  proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer       ERROR  - HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: hibe.core.communication.feed.Post
java.lang.RuntimeException: duplicate method: attach in hibe.core.communication.feed.Post_$$_javassist_64
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:509)
        at ...
```

See [Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/z3CRG9hjcQ) for my regex and a more complete input sample.

My regex works OK, except the `message` group, which fails to match the whole message: I need to have the `message` group to include the whole stacktrace until the next one. The pattern to know whether its the next one is the date to this format: 2015-01-28 18:48:33,484

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- the DOTALL flag, so dot matches newline too
- a lookahead to consume up to, but not including, the next date stamp
- the *reluctant* quantifier `*?`, so the match doesn't consume all the input up to the last datestamp

Like this:

```
(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]* ) (?<class>[^ ]+) *(?<level>[^ ]+)[ -]+(?<message>.*?(?=\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d{3}))
```

See [demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/mzFtbZ8BvI)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is there a way to have it without multine mode ?